# VSCode on Linux Mint 19 display menu bar right to left

Tags: visual-studio-code, multilingual, right-to-left, hebrew

I have installed VSCode in Linux Mint 19, having Hebrew locale and Language.

The result is VSCode menu bar is right to left, and menus are right aligned.
As shown bellow.

[image]

I wish to fix the menu bar direction and alignment.

More specifically:

I want menu bar to be left to right, and menus aligned to left.

I truly hope this is possible without extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer in settings `Title Bar Style = custom`.

Got the menu bar left to right, and menus are aligned to left.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug, the UI is not translated to Hebrew, so using an RTL menu seems... not smart. I wonder what else will you find. What triggers that behaviour? LC_C? LANG?